# Converting Python request.put to PowerShell Invoke-Restmethod

Tags: powershell

Struggling to get this working. This particular REST API is BlueCat (DDI software).

This works in Python:

`requests.put(url+'updateUserDefinedField', headers=login(loginacct, pwd), params=params_put, data=json.dumps(udf), verify=False)`

params and udf are both dictionaries.

We need this to work in PowerShell using Invoke-Restmethod. From what I've tried and read about, it seems both params and udf have to be in the -Body portion of the Invoke-Restmethod command. I've tried many combinations and just don't understand how to do this.

This might not be enough information, apologies in advance if that's the case. I can provide more if needed, but I'm hoping there is a simple answer that has not revealed itself to me via googling thus far.

Comment: What powershell code do you have, to start with?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I'm using v5.1